# W3C: Can't read EBNF's SPARQL IRIREF specification?

Tags: regex, sparql, w3c, bnf, ebnf

(Specifications: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rIRIREF)

According to the specification, an IRIREF can be parsed as this:

```
[139]   IRIREF    ::=   '<' ([^<>"{}|^`\]-[#x00-#x20])* '>'
```

What is bothering me is this part of the expression:

```
\]-[
```

If I consider `\` to be an escaping character in the bracketed character class (which would be the case in a Perl regular expression), then it means the `\` alone is not a problem in the IRIREF and this is valid: `<http://hello\world>`

Then there is this big problem with the range: `]-[`. The character `]` has an ordinal value of 93 and the `[` of 91. This means we have an invalid range: 93 to 92. This is not allowed in most regex engines I tested.

What does that means?

1. Should I consider the `-` as a regular character in the bracketed character class, then this is invalid IRIREF: `<http://new-example.org>`. It makes no sense.
2. Should I consider the range `]-[` null and this IRIREF is valid: `<http://hello[world]>`
3. What I think is more likely is that the range is inverted and is not a problem for w3c specifications, which means the characters `[`, `\` and `]` are invalid characters. This makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPARQL spec says that its grammar is written using the notation [defined by the XML 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#sec-notation).

In that notation, the right-hand side you quote,

```
'<' ([^<>"{}|^`\]-[#x00-#x20])* '>'
```

denotes a sequence of

- a '<' character
- zero or more characters matching the expression [^<>"{}|^`]-[#x00-#x20]; this is a set difference denoting

  - any character matched by [^<>"{}|^`\] = any character other than '<', '>', '"', '{', '}', '|', '^', '`', or '\'; n.b. '\' is not an escape character in this notation (which has no escape characters at all)
  - except those matched by [#x00-#x20] = the C1 area of control characters plus blank

  This is a slightly odd way to write this pattern; it could equally well be written as [^<>"{}|^`#x00-#x20]; I'm not sure why the editors wrote it the way they did.
- a '>' character

So to answer your questions one by one:

> Should I consider the - as a regular character in the bracketed character class, then this is invalid IRIREF: http://new-example.org. It makes no sense.

No.  When *A* and *B* are expressions in this notation, *A* - *B* denotes any string in the language of *A* that is not also a string in the language of *B*.  Here *A* and *B* are each character-class expressions, one negative and one positive.

You are right that it would make no sense to prohibit hyphens from a grammar rule intended to accept IRIs bracketed by angle brackets.

> Should I consider the range ]-[ null and this IRIREF is valid: http://hello[world]

']-[' does not denote a range here, null or otherwise; the `]` ends the first character class expression and the `[` begins the second.

> What I think is more likely is that the range is inverted and is not a problem for w3c specifications, which means the characters [, \ and ] are invalid characters. This makes sense.

If my parsing of the expression is correct, '[' and ']' are legal (they are not excluded by the first expression, and they are not excluded by the second); '\' is excluded by the first expression.

Comment: I think the `A - B` notation could make sense but, as you said, why would they do that if They can include the `[0x00-0x20]` directly in the first bracketed character class. What also makes me doubt is that the notation `A - B` is well spaced, but here it's a whole block. They usually space all different notations more, for instance: `"'" ( ([^#x27#x5C#xA#xD]) | ECHAR )* "'"`. And last but not least: `[` and `]` are characters we usually escape in URL with `%5B` and `%5D`.

Comment: I don't think there can be any doubt about the meaning of the expression:  the SPARQL spec documents its notation (by pointing to XML 1.1) and the expression is syntactically legal and unambiguous in the documented notation.  It may be unclear why the WG chose that particular way of expressing a constraint, or why they chose that particular constraint, but it's not at all unclear what constraint is in the spec.

Comment: I have discovered today that the rdflib for Python does not comply with "-" notation. Instead, they put `]`, \ and `[` directly in the bracketed character class: IRIREF = r'<([^<>"{}|^`\]\\\[\x00-\x20])*>' and they say "[it's] From the SPARQL grammar"

Answer (score 2):

This is shorthand syntactic sugar, `EBNF` to be precise, a syntax that transcends the standard features of regexen :

It means `prior character class without following character class`, in this particular instance `not certain brackets and quotes, and neither control codes from 0x00 (NUL) to 0x20 (SPC), which would otherwise be included`.

Pertinent reference: [EBNF notation used](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#sec-notation), in particular the clause `A - B`. It is referred to in the first paragraph of the [SPARQL grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#sparqlGrammar).

Comment: `\` is not a escape character in `[...]`.

Comment: @AndyS Please elaborate: ``` belongs to the set of characters not permitted in an `IRIREF`. NB: The backslash in the first character class does not need to be escaped; the syntax is EBNF, it abstracts away from use in the context of any programming language.

Comment: My comment got manged by the formatting.

\,  the backslash, is not special inside [ ]. It is just a character like any other. So all the characters between [^  and ] are excluded.

Comment: @AndyS You are correct, but this hasn't been the issue. The OP read the minus sign in the character class as a range operator in regex character classes while it actually is a set difference operator in ebnf.